# How to download large file into byte array

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to download large file using spring Rest Template:

```
    private Result download(Long id) throws Exception {
    Result result = new Result();
    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateFactory.getRestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.set(AUTHORIZATION, authorizationBL.getAccessToken().getAccessToken());
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(null, headers);
        Map<String, Long> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, Long>(1);
        valuesMap.put(ID, id);
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(downloadURL, HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);
        byte[] stream = response.getBody();
        result.setData(stream);
        result.setStatus(Result.Status.SUCCESS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

when file size is large lets say above 100 MB then I am getting issue:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.java:59) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.java:38) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:924) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:908) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:662) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:538) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

I increased heap size upto 10g but it also didn't help.

Comment: I need to convert large file into byte array for further processing

Comment: What does *further processing* mean?

Comment: You really should think about another way to achieve your business need.
Storing such a large amount of data in a byte-array is not a good idea.
If you provide your original goal, someone may help you with finding a robust way to achieve this. i.e. you can save it to a file for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downloading the file into a byte array, save it to disk. Then you can read it from wherever else you need to in your program. For example, changing your method to

```
/**
 * returns a File corresponding to the tmp file download for this resource
 */
private File download(Long id) throws IOException {
    File tmp = null;
    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateFactory.getRestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.set(AUTHORIZATION, authorizationBL.getAccessToken().getAccessToken());
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(null, headers);
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(downloadURL, HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            tmp = Files.createTempFile("yourprefix", "yoursuffix");
            Files.write(tmp.toPath(), response.getBody());
        } else {
            // TODO handle this case
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("An exception occurred while downloading", e);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

A few observations:

1. The `valuesMap` wasn't used anywhere (also removed)
2. `result` also removed

Comment: throwing `Exception` is discouraged. Preferably change it just to `IOException`

Comment: Also the `return tmp;` is invalid, `tmp` is only available inside the if-block

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue using stream instead storing file in byte[] & using `IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream)`.

Comment: Can you post your solution here in detail?